# Syntax highlighting methods

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting

I want to highlight some css code but i do not want to use the pre tag.I have seen many methods based on the pre tag however that i don't want to use the that tag.What other methods can be used to highlight the syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Syntax Highlighter](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter)?
It has lots of feature to help you in syntax-highlighting.

By the way why do you not want to use [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag? It is the only tag in HTML that preserves syntax like white-spaces.

Syntax Highlighter can also be used with `<script>` tag, see [here](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Usage#script--method).

Comment: That plugin uses the <pre> tag.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Answer (score 3):

Add CDN in head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.1/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

and finally in page just add

```
<pre>
  <code class="C#"> 
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
 </code>
</pre>
```

Thats it you dont need css to download as long as your site on internet.

Answer (score 1):

The `pre` element has nothing to do with syntax highlighting. You use text-level markup, and usually also CSS, inside that element for highlighting. Whatever tools you are using there can also be used inside a `div` element, for example, or `p` or `blockquote`.

The `pre` element is for **preformatted** text, in the sense that it preserves spaces and newlines. To achieve the same, you can use `white-space: pre` in CSS. As a side effect, `pre` also causes a monospace font to be used; for this, you can also use CSS, e.g. `font-family: Consolas, Courier New, monospace`, or HTML markup, e.g. .... Or you might decide that there is no compelling reason to use a monospace font for CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same library as StackOverflow: [google-code-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

You can put your code snippets inside a `<code>...</code>` tags instead of a `<pre>...</pre>` tags and it's very simple to use.